# read and write registry on a remote computer using c#

Tags: c#, registry, remote-access

First, I'm trying to read a registry key from a remote computer. I've seen [this example](http://www.rhyous.com/2011/08/07/how-to-authenticate-and-access-the-registry-remotely-using-c/) on how to do it. So my code looks like this:

```
string server = "myServer";
NetworkShare share = new NetworkShare(server, "ipc$");
share.Connect();

string name = "";
RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, server);

if (key != null)
{
    key = key.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System");

    if (key != null)
    {
        name = key.GetValue("DisableCMD").ToString();
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(name);
share.Disconnect();
```

But after the line `key = key.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System");`, the RegistryKey `key` is set to `null`. I checked the key path - it exists. I cannot figure out what's wrong.

Second, I'm trying to write a remote registry key. I think it is pretty similar to reading keys. I tried `SetValue()` method, but this throws me a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Cannot write to the registry key` exception.

Suggestions appreciated :)